# shorten code when use matchmedia

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use [matchmedia.addlistener](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/) to check windows size, my button event looks like this

```
$('button').click(function(){
    if(this.attr('aria-expanded') === 'false'){
        $this.attr('aria-expanded', true).next().fadeOut();
    }else{
       $this.attr('aria-expanded', false).next().fadeIn();
    }
});
```

if I use `matchmedia`, I will need to do it this way

```
minWidth768 = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)');

if(minWidth768.matches){
    $('button').click(function(){
        if(this.attr('aria-expanded') === 'false'){
            $this.attr('aria-expanded', true).next().slideUp();
        }else{
           $this.attr('aria-expanded', false).next().slideDown();
        }
    });
}else{
    $('button').click(function(){
        if(this.attr('aria-expanded') === 'false'){
            $this.attr('aria-expanded', true).next().fadeOut();
        }else{
           $this.attr('aria-expanded', false).next().fadeIn();
        }
    });
}
```

If i want to add an `addListener`, so I need to repeat my code again.

```
minWidth768.addListener(function(media) {
    if(media.matches){
      //repeat;
    }else{
      //repeat;
    }
});
```

Is there a way I could make  my code shorter, and make code looks nice and easy to maintain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function and then call that function wherever you need.

Eg.

```
function matchMedia(){
//do stuff here
}

//now call where you want

if(true){
  matchMedia();
}
```

But note: if you want to call the function inside the function parameter then you no need to use parenthesis like below is an example:

```
setTimeout(matchMedia, 400);// don't do matchMedia()
```